# Как обновить данные (увеличить число) в бд Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, update

Приветствую, покажите пожалуйста правильно, как обновить данные в таблице бд, а именно у меня в таблице balance для пользователя "user" стоит сумма "10" рублей, я хочу чтобы после отправки денег суммой "25" рублей для пользователя "user" его 10 рублей стали "35" рублей, вот мой код, но оно вместо того чтобы увеличить и сделать баланс пользователя "user" на 25 рублей больше т.е 35 рублей в общем оно удаляет его 10 рублей и добавляет 25 рублей

```
                     $db_user = ('my_users') ;
                     $this->db->set('user_balance', '+'.$sum.'');
                     $this->db->where('user_login', 
                     $user_receiver['username']);
                     $this->db->update($db_user);
```

Раньше я это реализовал на простом PHP следующим образом:
$query ="UPDATE my_users SET user_balance = user_balance+{$Sum} WHERE email ='{$Receiver}'";

Тоесть: user_balance+{$Sum} (плюсовал поверх)
В Codeigniter как это правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Использовать simple_query :

```
$this->db->simple_query("UPDATE my_users SET user_balance = user_balance+{$Sum} WHERE email ='{$Receiver}'");
```